# ThreadingTCPServer vs ThreadingMixIn HTTPServer

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, ssl

I have programmed two servers that essentiall do the same with different methods. Both are webservers with a non-blocking ssl wrapper around the socket object. Threads allow multiple requests to be served at the same time.

One uses ThreadingTCPServer and the other calls ThreadingMixIn on the HTTPServer module.
Which one should I use and why if any of them is better than the other?

ThreadingMixIn on the HTTPServer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, ssl
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

MYSERV_WORKDIR = "/media/kingdian/server_pub"
#MYSERV_CLIENTCRT = "/home/ran/keys/client.pem"
MYSERV_FULLCHAIN = "/home/ran/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/fullchain.cer"
MYSERV_PRIVKEY = "/home/ran/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/example.com.key"

global sslcontext
sslcontext = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
sslcontext.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
sslcontext.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
#sslcontext.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2
#sslcontext.protocol = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS
#sslcontext.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
sslcontext.set_ciphers("ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305")
sslcontext.set_ecdh_curve("secp384r1")
#sslcontext.load_verify_locations(MYSERV_CLIENTCRT)
sslcontext.load_cert_chain(MYSERV_FULLCHAIN, MYSERV_PRIVKEY)

class HSTSHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_header("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload")
        self.send_header("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'")
        self.send_header("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
        self.send_header("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN")
        self.send_header("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block")
        self.send_header("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer")
        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    daemon_threads = True

def main():
    try:
        os.chdir(MYSERV_WORKDIR)#auto-change working directory
        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.sys_version = "002"#display custom Python system version
        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.server_version = "001"#display custom server software version
        my_server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('', 443), HSTSHandler)
        my_server.socket = sslcontext.wrap_socket(my_server.socket, do_handshake_on_connect=False, server_side=True)
        print('Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop')
        my_server.serve_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(' received, shutting down server')
        my_server.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ThreadingTCPServer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, ssl, socketserver
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

MYSERV_WORKDIR = "/media/kingdian/server_pub"
#MYSERV_CLIENTCRT = "/home/ran/keys/client.pem"
MYSERV_FULLCHAIN = "/home/ran/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/fullchain.cer"
MYSERV_PRIVKEY = "/home/ran/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/example.com.key"

global sslcontext
sslcontext = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
sslcontext.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
sslcontext.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
#sslcontext.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2
#sslcontext.protocol = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS
#sslcontext.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
sslcontext.set_ciphers("ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305")
sslcontext.set_ecdh_curve("secp384r1")
#sslcontext.load_verify_locations(MYSERV_CLIENTCRT)
sslcontext.load_cert_chain(MYSERV_FULLCHAIN, MYSERV_PRIVKEY)

class HSTSHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_header("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload")
        self.send_header("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'")
        self.send_header("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
        self.send_header("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN")
        self.send_header("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block")
        self.send_header("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer")
        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)

def main():
    try:
        os.chdir(MYSERV_WORKDIR)#auto-change working directory
        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.sys_version = "002"#display custom Python system version
        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.server_version = "001"#display custom server software version
        my_server = socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer(('', 443), HSTSHandler)
        my_server.socket = sslcontext.wrap_socket(my_server.socket, do_handshake_on_connect=False, server_side=True)
        print('Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop')
        my_server.serve_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(' received, shutting down server')
        my_server.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: None of these options is really a good idea since they both do the SSL handshake inside the main thread and only after the handshake create a new thread to handle the request. If someone is doing a simple TCP connect to the server (without TLS handshake) no more connections will be possible as long as this client stays connected and is not advancing with the TLS handshake.

Comment: Looks like the documentation of `do_handshake_on_connect` is misleading: it will not only apply to `ssl.connect` as documented but also to `ssl.accept`. And the application also does not need to call `ssl.do_handshake` explicitly as claimed if this parameter is `False` but this is implicitly handled on the first read or write.  Taking this undocumented behavior in account the options makes sense. It has no effect on the security of TLS since it just changes when the TLS handshake is done but does not change the TLS handshake itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are pretty much two different ways to get to the same end result. If you look at the implementation of `ThreadingTCPServer`, it's just:

```
class ThreadingTCPServer(ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer): pass
```

In the other example, `HTTPServer` is just a very small wrapper around `TCPServer` (adds an override in `server_bind` to store the server hostname and automatically sets `allow_reuse_address`) and then your code is directly adding the `ThreadingMixIn`.

So, ultimately, you're going through the same basic code either way. The class hierarchy in the python library has changed slightly over time and so different code examples have ended up doing things in different combinations.

Personally, for your examples, I find the version that uses `ThreadingTCPServer` cleaner, just because one extra class is handled elsewhere and the code is slightly smaller therefore. OTOH, the other version allows slightly more flexibility since you've already defined a point at which you can control attributes of the threading mix-in, plus you get the additional `HTTPServer` wrapper bits if that should become important to you.